# поиск подстроки в строке C++ с использованием char*

Tags: c++, char

Создавал программу по поиску подстроки в строке и возвращению адреса этой подстроки. Обязательным условием является использование char* str...

Столкнулся с целым рядом проблем при работе с char* str.
Компилятор посстоянно выдает ошибки с обработкой данных в куче.
Привожу код программы, думаю что ошибка непостредственно в функции main

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
const int n = 128;
//поиск подстроки в стркое
//возвращение адреса подстроки
char* FirstPStr(char* strRez, char* str)
{  char* st = new char[strlen(str)+1];
int t=0;
for(unsigned int i=0;i<strlen(strRez);i++)
{
while(strRez[i]==str[t])
    st[t++]=strRez[i++];
st[t] ='\0';
t=0;
if(strcmp(st, str)==0) return &strRez[i-strlen(str)];
}
return 0;

}
//преобразование символа из заглавного в строный
int Lower(char& s){
if(isalpha(s))
 if(isupper(s)){ s=tolower(s);
   return 1; }
 return 0;
}
//поиск подстроки в строке и преобразование символа перед ней в строчную
//возвращение адреса строки если произошло преобразование символа перед 
подстрокой
char* LowerSymb(char* strRez, char* str, int& kol){
char* st = new char[strlen(str)+1];
int t=0;
for(unsigned  int i=0;i<strlen(strRez);i++)
{
while(strRez[i]==str[t])
    st[t++]=strRez[i++];
st[t] ='\0';
t=0;
kol+=Lower(strRez[i-strlen(str)-1]);
}
if(kol!=0) return &strRez[0];
return 0;
}


void main(int argc, char* argv[]){
char* strRez= new char[n];
char* str =new char[n];
int kol=0;
cout<<"enter strRez"<<'\n';
gets(strRez);
cout<<"enter str"<<'\n';
gets(str);
cout<<"adress of first substr "<<FirstPStr(strRez,str)<<endl;
cout<<"adress of string if symbols changed "<<LowerSymb(strRez,str,kol) 
<<endl;
system("Pause");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Твой код сложно понять, у тебя достаточно неясный алгоритм. Поэтому предложу свой вариант решения:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int n = 128;

char *FirstPStr(char* strRez, char* str)
{
    if (strlen(strRez) > strlen(str))
    {
        return NULL;
    }


    for (int i = 0; i <= strlen(str) - strlen(strRez); i++)
    {
        char *newStr = new char[n];
        for (int j = 0; j < strlen(strRez); j++)
        {
            newStr[j] = str[i + j];
        }

        if (strcmp(newStr, strRez) == 0)
        {
            return newStr;
        }
        delete[] newStr;
    }

    return NULL;
}

int main() {
    char *str = "aaaba";
    char *strRez = "aba";
    char *newStr = FirstPStr(strRez, str);
    cout << str << " " << strRez << " " << newStr;


    return 0;
}
```

Алгоритм: есть исходная строка `str` и искомая подстрока `strRez`. Если длина `strRez` больше, чем длина `str`, возвращаем нулевой указатель. Внутри цикла мы перебираем все входящие в `str` подстроки длины `strlen(strRez)`. Если находится подстрока, равная `strRez`, то возвращаем указатель на нее. Если такой строки не найдется - вернем `NULL`.

Если надо сделать то же самое без учета регистра, то замени строку `if (strcmp(newStr, strRez) == 0)` на `if (strcmp(tolower(newStr), tolower(strRez)) == 0)`, где `tolower` - функция, изменяющая заглавные символы на строчные. Не забывай про очистку памяти.

Ввод строки:

```
char *readLine() {
    char *str = new char[1];

    char ch = 0;
    int i = 0;
    while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && (ch != '\0')) {
        str[i++] = ch;

        char *copyStr = new char[i + 1];
        strncpy(copyStr, str, i);

        delete[] str;
        str = copyStr;
    }
    str[i] = '\0';

    return str;
}
```

Comment: Ваш алгоритм понятен, а как реализовать ввод строки из консоли? через gets(str)?

Comment: @АдамГремори дополнил ответ. Прошу принять ответ (галочка слева от вопроса)

Comment: Принял, спасибо за разъяснение.